# How to make Jquery DataTable Column as HyperLink or ActionLink with other column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to pass the Value of the first column into the second column ***render function()*** to make a hyperlink where the value of the first column is parameter. of the hyperlink.

```
"Columns": [
    {
        "data": "Code", "autoWidth": true,
    },

    {   "data" : "StyleReference","autoWidth": true,
        "render": function (data, oObj) {
            return '<a href="/Production/Styles/StyleDetails/' + Code + '">' + data + '</a>';
        }
    }
]
```

**Any Help Please!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. The render function can take up to [4 variables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Your `row` represents the whole object, this should work:

```
"columns": [{
  "data": "Code",
  "autoWidth": true
}, {
  "data": "StyleReference",
  "autoWidth": true,
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<a href="/Production/Styles/StyleDetails/' + row.Code + '">' + data + '</a>';
  }
}]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh!! I have spend too much time on it!! A huge heartfelt Thanks for your kind answer!!!